# how does system call Profile on Automapper?

Tags: .net-core, automapper

I use Automapper to cast my DTOs in DotNet core without any problem. It works fine.

But I wondering to know how the system calls my class that is driven from Profile class?

```
 public class ViewModelToEntityMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public ViewModelToEntityMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<RegistrationViewModel, AppUser>().ForMember(au => au.UserName, map => map.MapFrom(vm => vm.Email));
    }
}
```

The above class is necessary to cast my classes. But I'm wondering how it called ViewModelToEntityMappingProfile class when I call my API Methods without any direct calls ? there is also doesn't show any reference that used it in IDE.

My API (just for extra information)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] RegistrationViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        try
        {
            var userIdentity = _mapper.Map<AppUser>(model);

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userIdentity, model.Password);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(Errors.AddErrorsToModelState(result, ModelState));

            await _appDbContext.Customers.AddAsync(new Customer { IdentityId = userIdentity.Id, Location = model.Location });

            await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return new OkObjectResult("Account created");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

    }
```

Comment: [Here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/07/20/integrating-automapper-with-asp-net-core-di/) is how the DI package is implemented. Of course you can find the source code on GitHub.

Comment: I know about DI and I know that Auto mapper injects via startup in dot net core but what I don't understand is specific about that mentioned class. It never injects somewhere but calls exactly before the API Method call.By the way thanks for your link.

Comment: Take the time and try to understand that blog post because it explains how things work, including what you're asking.